# Do druids need things to cast spells

Tags: spellcasting, druid, spell-components

I have not played a spell caster and was going to play a Druid Circle of the Shepherd and was wondering if when casting spells I need components like a wizard or some clerics need to cast their spells. Components like needing a diamond worth about $300 or do I need bat dropping and Sulfur to cast something?

Comment: Hello Colin and welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to have some guidance on how posting questions/answers on the website! Which rpg are you playing? And what edition?

Comment: We do need to know what game (and edition) you are playing, as Eddymage said above. Additionally, have you read the rules for spellcasting? It seems to me that your question can be answered by simply quoting the particular rules section, but if you have already read those rules and are still confused, that won't really help you. Is there some particular part of the spellcasting rules that is confusing to you? If we knew a little more about what you have read and what about it did not make sense, we would be better equipped to help you.

Comment: I would guess dungeons and dragons 5e, but there are no dollars in the game.